# What information is present in the ACPI tables?

Tags: power-management, acpi

What do ACPI tables contain?

I tried googling it, and it did not help.

Answer (score 1):

On a rather abstract level the ACPI tables contain (from [Advanced Configuration and Power Interface](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Advanced_Configuration_and_Power_Interface)):

> ... description of system hardware in a platform-independent manner, and are presented as either fixed formatted data structures or in ACPI Machine Language (AML). The main AML table is the DSDT (differentiated system description table).
>
> The Root System Description Pointer is located in a platform-dependent manner, and describes the rest of the tables.